# I changed "hdd1\Content" folder with JTAG console, how to restore and update this folder

Tags: xbox360

I changed "hdd1\Content" folder with JTAG console, how to restore and update this folder, because xbox hangs up.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a development kit Xbox 360, try accessing the retail emulation partition from neighbourhood (assuming the kernel boots) and renaming it there. If that fails, do a recovery.

If it's a retail Xbox 360, you might need to somehow connect your hard drive to a computer and  find an XFAT tool that will enable you to rename the folder back to `Content`. Your console should boot fine if you detach the hard drive. Until you manage to fix the problem, you can probably still play by detaching the HDD and using a flash drive for storage.

EDIT: I know this question is a few months old now (and the issue is probably resolved), but hopefully this information may be useful to others in the same situation.